# Python-Jenkins tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, json, api, jenkins

I have been using the Python Jenkins APIs to manager my Jenkins jobs. It has worked for a long time, but it stopped suddenly working. This is the code excerpt:

```
import jenkins

server = jenkins.Jenkins('https://jenkins.company.com', username='xxxx', password='password')
server._session.verify = False
print(server.jobs_count())
```

The traceback:

> File "", line 1, in 
> server.jobs_count()
>
> File "E:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jenkins_*init*_.py", line
> 1160, in jobs_count
> return len(self.get_all_jobs())
>
> File "E:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jenkins_*init*_.py", line
> 1020, in get_all_jobs
> jobs = [(0, [], self.get_info(query=jobs_query)['jobs'])]
>
> File "E:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jenkins_*init*_.py", line 769,
> in get_info
> requests.Request('GET', self._build_url(url))
>
> File "E:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jenkins_*init*_.py", line 557,
> in jenkins_open
> return self.jenkins_request(req, add_crumb, resolve_auth).text
>
> File "E:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jenkins_*init*_.py", line 573,
> in jenkins_request
> self.maybe_add_crumb(req)
>
> File "E:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jenkins_*init*_.py", line 371,
> in maybe_add_crumb
> 'GET', self._build_url(CRUMB_URL)), add_crumb=False)
>
> File "E:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jenkins_*init*_.py", line 557,
> in jenkins_open
> return self.jenkins_request(req, add_crumb, resolve_auth).text
>
> File "E:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jenkins_*init*_.py", line 576,
> in jenkins_request
> self._request(req))
>
> File "E:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jenkins_*init*_.py", line 550,
> in _request
> return self._session.send(r, **_settings)
>
> File "E:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line
> 622, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>
> File "E:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line
> 507, in send
> raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
>
> ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jenkins.company.com', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url:
> /job/scp/job/sm/job/9218/job/4198/job/SIT/crumbIssuer/api/json (Caused
> by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection
> failed: 403 Forbidden')))

Note that there isn't any proxy on the Jenkins server, and I can use the user/password logon to the Jenkins server without any issues.

I have the crum id and API token, but I haven't found anything that is indicating how to add the crum into the Python-Jenkins API.

Comment: Setting `verify` to False appears to be irrelevant. It's a cert check, and you don't even get far enough in the protocol to learn any server cert details.

Comment: this is a test, shortest code snip that points to the issue, and generate the exact trace, yes, the cert line has nothing to do with the issue

Comment: What is "crum"? Not "[crumb](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/csrf-protection/)"?

Answer (score 1):

The final part of the traceback says:

```
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ebs.usps.gov', port=443)
```

Which most likely indicates that you have proxy settings that your Python code inherits from somewhere when it runs. It could be environment variables ((HTTP|HTTPS)_PROXY) on [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) sort of platforms or something similar... If you need to to use a proxy to reach the Jenkins instance, then the issue is in the proxy itself. It blocks your access for some reason. If you do not need to use a proxy, then you should remove the settings affecting your Python code when you run it.

Also, see what [J_H said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74647215/python-jenkins-tunnel-connection-failed-403-forbidden/74647371#74647371)...

Comment: Something seems to be missing at the end.

Comment: I am looking for help specifically with the `Python-Jenkins package`. i have no problem with proxy settings with the `curl` command, and python `webdriver` to connect to the same jenkins installation, Both use proxy.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: You lack connectivity.

The jenkins library depends on `import requests`,
which is reporting the connectivity error.
Regrettably, it uses ProxyError in the diagnostic.
The rationale goes like this:

- We're making a [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request for the application.
- Optionally the "GET from server S" will be turned into "GET from proxy P" if proxying is in use.
- Eventually we try to contact some host, S or P. Might as well tell a proxy user that state of S is unknown, but state of P is "down".

Here ends the "why mention proxying?" diagnostic rant.

When you say "I'm not using proxying", I believe you.
The diagnostic can be a bit of a red herring for
folks who are not yet familiar with it.

---

When I probe ebs.usps.gov (56.207.107.97) on ports 443, 80, or with ICMP, I see zero response packets.
You're in a different part of the net, with different
filters between you and server, so your mileage might vary.
I wouldn't describe that host as a "public server",
since it offers me no responses.

---

It appears you sent [SYN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) to tcp port 443,
and either some network device discarded that packet,
or the server replied with SYN-ACK and that
reply packet was discarded.

Most likely the server is down or your request was discarded.

Comment: the jenkins servers and i run my python scripts behind firewall, no access whatever from outside is possible.

Comment: When I try to connect, I lack connectivity. When you try to connect, you lack connectivity. I was just reading your stack trace, which explains that the server wasn't going to return a GET response to your client.